How do I refresh a changelist?
I created a changelist initially with some files say
A.txt
B.txt
C.txt

Now I updated C.txt in my local space. But the changelist was not updated. How do I refresh the changelist so that the same is visible to others who open the changelist.

Do you mean a submitted changelist, or a shelved changelist?  Submitted changelists are immutable, and you need to submit a new changelist on top of it for the depot to show your changes.  Shelved changelists can be updated with p4 shelve.

Added files to changelist but did not shelve or submit.

If it's only a pending changelist, the files in it are only available in your workspace.  You need to shelve or submit to get the change onto the server where other people can open it.
